# Change RecyclerView scrollBar width

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-scrollbar, recyclerview-layout

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ddd"
        android:fadeScrollbars="true"
        android:scrollbarSize="12dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
```

I am testing the code on 5.1.1. Changing `android:scrollbarSize` has no effect. I tried increasing and decreasing it, no change.

How to change the width?

Answer (score 14):

Now, I tell you a method,you can try it and then you will know the answer:
add the following codes:

```
android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@color/colorAccent"
```

the whole block like this:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/RV_hot_latest"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@color/colorAccent"
    android:scrollbarSize="18dp"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"/>
```

Now ,you will find you `android:scrollbarSize` has effect.
Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You have one of two oportunities:

1) Change drawable of scrollbar through `android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/yoursdrawablefile`

2) Work with scrollbar programmatically through `onDrawHorizontalScrollBar` and `onDrawVerticalScrollBar` callbacks.

Please, [first two answers of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35399829/scrollbar-color-in-recyclerview) for more details.

Comment: why changing the attribute in xml doesn't work? is it known bug?

Answer (score -1):

1. Horizontal RecyclerView

   ```
   android:scrollbars="horizontal"
   android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="@color/horizontal_color"
   android:scrollbarSize="1dp"
   ```
2. Vertical RecyclerView ( default android:scrollbars="vertical")

   ```
   android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="@color/vertical_color"
   android:scrollbarSize="1dp"
   ```