# How to implment a custom scroll bar in android

Tags: android, scroll

I have a recycler view but scrolling is disabled on the recycler view . I want to implement a custom scroll bar for that recycler view without considering recycler view scrolling .

Is there a way add a scroll bar separately and programatically control the scroll within the bar based on some action .

Comment: i belive alezniki has Answer for you try it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46414207/16290160)

Comment: Try looking at [How to scroll recyclerView programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48862643/how-to-scroll-recyclerview-programmatically)